# Install VirtualBox with yum in Oracle Linux 7

Tags: yum, oracle-linux

I have Oracle Linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) ) runnig fine, but now I want to install VirtualBox with yum.

On [this page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) I can only find the instruction

```
Users of Oracle Linux 6 and 7 can use the Oracle Linux yum  repository and enable the  ol6_developer channel for Oracle Linux 6 or the  ol7_developer channel for Oracle Linux 7.
```

I have these files

```
ls -1 /etc/yum.repos.d/

epel-yum-ol7.repo
oracle-linux-ol7.repo
oracle-softwarecollection-ol7.repo
pgdg-redhat-all.repo
uek-ol7.repo
virt-ol7.repo
```

so any command of enabling ol7_developer

```
yum-config-manager --enable ol7_developer
```

doesnt seem to do any difference.

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the repository manually. Add the following line to `/etc/yum.repos.d/ol7_developper.repo`:

```
[ol7_developer]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Development Packages ($basearch)
baseurl=http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Or install the `rpm`:

```
wget https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.2_135662_el7-1.x86_64.rpm
wget http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/containerd-1.2.0-1.0.4.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.2_135662_el7-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh containerd-1.2.0-1.0.4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Solved it. Thanks.